# Android how to implement Google Analytics (V4)

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to include Google Analytics to my Android project.

Following the Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), i'm having trouble in this part:

```
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

What is the R.xml.global_tracker? where can i get it from? i have downloaded their sample code from GitHub and still cannot find that XML file.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have found that XML, but Analytics is not tracking my actions, here is my updated code:

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-xxxxxxx-x</string>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">1800</integer>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">false</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <screenName name="com.pkgname.activities.blabla">blabla</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.pkgname.activities.blabla2">blabla2</screenName>
</resources>
```

Application Class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private Tracker mTracker;

    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.tracker_config);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Tracker tracker = getDefaultTracker();      
    }
}
```

Shouldn't it start automatically start tracking my activities?

Comment: Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: It looks like the code in the guide may not be updated. This looks like the way that it should be done.  https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app

Comment: can you tell us where you found the bloody xml file ?

Comment: here are the list of parameters you can use https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/parameters